# Error while taking screenshot using uiAutomatorviewer

Tags: android, appium, android-uiautomator

When I am trying to capture the screen shot of my Android device using Uiautomatorviewer, I am getting an error stating:

> Error obtaining UI hierarchy. Reason:Error taking device screenshot:null

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

When there is any process going around which might accessing your App, this error is generated, just stop your appium server or any other interfering process and try again, Also try to disconnect and reconnect device might help.
(Please ask Programming related questions on this site, this question is not suitable)

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect and reconnect device and try again